# class or interface expected after a bracket

Tags: android

i cant figure this one out but the bracket just before onCreateOptionsMenu says a space to the right of it that it expects a class or interface. help i just cant figure this one out! i really dont know what is going on.

```
package com.spizer.mizer2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DifficultyMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

private int T1;
private int T2;
private int T3;
private int T4;

private String S1;
private String S2;
private String S3;
private String S4;


ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_difficulty_menu);

    // get the list view
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // List view Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // List view Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // List view Group collapsed listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // List view on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

    /*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("AdditionDifficulty");
    listDataHeader.add("SubtractionDifficulty");
    listDataHeader.add("MultiplicationDifficulty");
    listDataHeader.add("DivisionDifficulty");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> AdditionDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(true) {
        if(T1<10) {
            String S1 = Integer.toString(T1);
            AdditionDifficulty.add(S1);
            T1++;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> SubtractionDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(true) {
        if(T2<10) {
            String S2 = Integer.toString(T2);
            SubtractionDifficulty.add(S2);
            T2++;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> MultiplicationDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(true) {
        if(T3<10) {
            String S3 = Integer.toString(T3);
            MultiplicationDifficulty.add(S3);
            T3++;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> DivisionDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(true) {
        if(T4<10) {
            String S4 = Integer.toString(T4);
            DivisionDifficulty.add(S4);
            T4++;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), AdditionDifficulty); // Header,        Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), SubtractionDifficulty);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), MultiplicationDifficulty);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), DivisionDifficulty);
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_difficulty_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: When you're coding, make sure you make the indents correctly. Usually, if you are using an IDE like Eclipse or Android Studio, it will automatically indent for you. It looks like you might have put an extra close curly right in front of the method. If it were indented correctly, you can tell at a glance that you've gotten a method where a class should be.

Comment: could you submit an answer correcting my mistake cause im not sure i am understanding you right.

Comment: I mean, if your code was properly indented, all of the braces on the same level of indent would be the same, so everything along one indent would be classes and everything along another indent would be methods, for example. Then you would have realized that you had a method on the same level as a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second brace right before your method is extraneous. Your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method then thinks it's outside any class, which is a no-no in Java.

```
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), DivisionDifficulty);
}
} // Remove me!

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
}
```

Here is your code with proper indentation applied. This makes it clearer that the activity class ends too early:

```
package com.spizer.mizer2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DifficultyMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int T1;
    private int T2;
    private int T3;
    private int T4;

    private String S1;
    private String S2;
    private String S3;
    private String S4;

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_difficulty_menu);

        // get the list view
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // List view Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // List view Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // List view Group collapsed listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // List view on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("AdditionDifficulty");
        listDataHeader.add("SubtractionDifficulty");
        listDataHeader.add("MultiplicationDifficulty");
        listDataHeader.add("DivisionDifficulty");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> AdditionDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(true) {
            if(T1<10) {
                String S1 = Integer.toString(T1);
                AdditionDifficulty.add(S1);
                T1++;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        List<String> SubtractionDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(true) {
            if(T2<10) {
                String S2 = Integer.toString(T2);
                SubtractionDifficulty.add(S2);
                T2++;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        List<String> MultiplicationDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(true) {
            if(T3<10) {
                String S3 = Integer.toString(T3);
                MultiplicationDifficulty.add(S3);
                T3++;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        List<String> DivisionDifficulty = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(true) {
            if(T4<10) {
                String S4 = Integer.toString(T4);
                DivisionDifficulty.add(S4);
                T4++;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), AdditionDifficulty); // Header,        Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), SubtractionDifficulty);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), MultiplicationDifficulty);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), DivisionDifficulty);
    }
} // The problematic brace

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_difficulty_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: ive tried doing it but its supposed to close off onCreate back up at the top

Comment: The `onCreate` is closed off by the brace above the `prepareListData` method, isn't it?

Comment: well i removed it cause it would get linked to the brace attached to onCreate at the top, when it needs to be attached to the one at the bottom before onCreateoptionsmenu, and now right where the semicolon is above it, it says } expected

Comment: not really now at the very last brace it says it expects a }

Comment: i have fixed it! i added an extra brace at the very bottom of the code and removed the problem brace all together. and now it works yay.